# SlidingMenu Library with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

In the documentar from SlidingMenu is written down:

> Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend Sherlock__Activity instead of __Activity.

The setup should be ok, I followed the guide, but if I try to extend my `Activity` with for example: `SlidingSherlockFragmentActivity` or `SherlockSlidingFragmentActivity` doesn't work.

If I extend my `Activity` with `SherlockFragmentActivity` I can't get the `SlidingMenu` with `getSlidingMenu()` or call `setBehindContentView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, go into the `SlidingMenu` library and extend the `Activity` by `SherlockFragmentActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Go to activities of library SlidingMenu and extends all activities to SherlockActivities corresponding, after go to your app and extends all activities to SlidingActivity corresponding.

Example: SlidingMenu:

```
SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity
SlidingMapActivity extends SherlockMapActivity
```

Example: MyClass

```
MyClass extends SlidingActivity
MyClass extends SlidingMapActivity
```